# Can reactions be controlled electromagnetically

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrochemistry

Since reactions involve the movement of electrons, Can't electromagnetism be used to control which path the electrons take and thus control the reaction?

Comment: You may wish to google such things as "spin chemistry", "plasma chemistry", etc. For example, see Pure Appl. Chem., Vol. 81, No. 1, pp. 19–43, 2009 ("Magnetic field effects in chemical systems"), for effects of magnetic field in chemical reactions.

Comment: So, photosynthesis, electroplating, battery charge/discharge; do those count?

Answer (score 2):

On a more detailed level to akhmeteli's answer, the control of chemical reactions by using pulses of radiation with durations on  the order of the chemical reaction ($\lesssim$ picoseconds or so) is a growing but well-established field, though the class of reactions that can be addressed is still rather limited.

Some references to get started:

- Quantum control of chemical reactions. M Shapiro and P Brumer. [*J. Chem. Soc., Faraday Trans.* **93**, 1263-1277 (1997)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/A605920A).
- *Principles of the Quantum Control of Molecular Processes*. M Shapiro and P Brumer. [Wiley-Interscience, Hoboken, N.J, 2003](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003pqcm.book.....S).
- Quantum Control of Gas-Phase and Liquid-Phase Femtochemistry. T Brixner and G Gerber. [*Chem. Phys. Phys. Chem.* **4**, 418 (2003)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cphc.200200581); [author eprint](http://www.phys-chemie.uni-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/08050100/AK-Brixner/Veroeffentlichungen/EinzelPDFs/ChemPhysChem4_418.pdf).
- Quantum control: May the electric force be with you. A Stolow. [*Nature Chem* **6**, 759 (2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nchem.2037)

and, generally, anything with the keywords 'quantum control' or 'coherent control', such as the references in [the Wikipedia article for the latter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_control).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are chemical reactions which change the dipole and magnetic moments of the reacting chemicals. If a magnetic or electric field is applied it can move molecules around in a fluid based on their charge, dipole moment, and magnetic moment.

Lets say we have an tank of chemicals $A^+$, $B^-$, and $C$. They are in an equilibrium reaction.

$A^++B^-\leftrightarrow C$

If an electric field is applied to the tank, the positive and negative charges will increase in concentration on opposite sides of the tank. This will inhibit them reacting together to form $C$. As a result of this, the equilibrium will shift to the left. Here are some useful links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotachophoresis
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophoresis
- http://web.archive.org/web/20110303222309/http://www-d0.fnal.gov/hardware/cal/lvps_info/engineering/elementmagn.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex#Magnetism
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetochemistry